# general recipe for reversing order of Functors (one foldable)

Tags: functional-programming, f#

lets say I have something like

```
#r @"nuget: FSharpPlus"

open FSharpPlus

let maybeXs: Option<List<int>> = Some [1]
```

and I want to transform it to a List<Option> out of it.

is there a formulaic mechanism?

```
let unit = Some

let almostThere: Option<List<Option<int>>> = map (fun xs -> map unit xs) maybeXs
```

I just need to 'eliminate' the outer option....which then seems to be specific to my data type so

```
let there: List<Option<int>> = 
    fold (fun s t -> t) [] (map (fun xs -> map unit xs) maybeXs)
```

is this a fair recipe to do this in general? or is there some functional magical recipe, that brings some clarity?

Comment: To elaborate on Mark's answer about `sequence`, great article by Scott Wlaschin : https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/elevated-world-4/

Comment: yep thats where I ended up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you have a stack of `Functors`, and the outer `Functor` is `Traversable`, a *traversal* flips the order. You can use `sequence` to simply flip the two:

```
let there = sequence maybeXs
```

This produces `[Some 1]`.

Comment: ooo...let me think about this